# What is the point of SSE2 instructions such as orpd?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, instruction-set, sse2

The `orpd` instruction is a "bitwise logical OR of packed double precision floating point values". Doesn't this do exactly the same thing as `por` ("bitwise logical OR")? If so, what's the point of having it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that SSE1 [`orps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/orps) came first.  (Well actually [MMX `por mm, mm/mem`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/por) came even before SSE1.)

Having the same opcode with a new prefix be the [SSE2 `orpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/orpd) instruction makes sense for hardware decoder logic, I guess, just like `movapd` vs. `movaps`.  Several instructions like this are redundant between between `ps` and `pd` versions, but some aren't, like `addps` vs. `addpd` or `unpcklps` vs. `unpcklpd` being different shuffles.

The reason for SSE2 also introducing [`66 0F EB /r  por xmm,xmm/mem`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/por) is at least partly for consistency with MMX `0F EB /r  por mm, mm/mem`, again same opcode with a new mandatory prefix.  Just like `paddb mm, mm` vs. `paddb xmm, xmm`.

But also for the possibility of different bypass-forwarding domains for vec-integer vs. FP.  Different microarchitectures have had different behaviours for how they actually decoded and ran those different instructions.  Some ran all the XMM `or` instructions the same way, creating extra latency for forwarding between FP and simd-integer domains.

No CPUs have ever actually had different fowarding domains for FP-float vs. FP-double, so yes, **`movapd` and `orpd` are in practice useless wastes of space that you should never use.  Use the smaller `orps` encoding instead.**

(Or with VEX encoding it doesn't matter; `vorps` and `vorpd` are the same size: 2 byte prefix + opcode + modrm ...)

---

### `por` vs. `orps`

For more about bypass delay when using `por` between FP math instructions like `addps`, or `orps` between SIMD-integer insns like `paddb`, see

- [Do I get a performance penalty when mixing SSE integer/float SIMD instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996384/do-i-get-a-performance-penalty-when-mixing-sse-integer-float-simd-instructions/4998071#4998071)
- [What's the difference between logical SSE intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804902/whats-the-difference-between-logical-sse-intrinsics/31233017#31233017)
- [Difference between the AVX instructions vxorpd and vpxor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942952/difference-between-the-avx-instructions-vxorpd-and-vpxor)
- [Does using mix of pxor and xorps affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811577/does-using-mix-of-pxor-and-xorps-affect-performance)
- [Is there any situation where using MOVDQU and MOVUPD is better than MOVUPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854819/is-there-any-situation-where-using-movdqu-and-movupd-is-better-than-movups)
- [Choosing SSE instruction execution domains in mixed contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660698/choosing-sse-instruction-execution-domains-in-mixed-contexts) - pre-Skylake, integer versions have better throughput.
- semi-related but maybe not for bitwise booleans: [Haswell AVX/FMA latencies tested 1 cycle slower than Intel's guide says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116679/haswell-avx-fma-latencies-tested-1-cycle-slower-than-intels-guide-says) - domain-crossing extra latency can persist indefinitely and affect the latency for the *other* operand, on Haswell/Skylake at least.

---

And in case anyone was wondering, the answer to the other interpretation of the title: bitwise booleans on FP values are mostly used to set, clear, or toggle the sign bit.  Or to do stuff with `cmpps/pd` masks like blending, or just zeroing element where a compare was true or false (ANDN or AND).

Comment: Is there any effect on performance if switching between integer and floating point instructions?

Comment: @rcgldr: yes, [What's the difference between logical SSE intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233017)

Comment: If I recall correctly, the first implementation of the AMD Opteron incurred a delay when switching between SIMD data types (even of the same width).  I think that this applied to float vs double as well as FP vs int, but it has been about 15 years....

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: Agner's uarch guide says float in general is one domain on K8/K10. 
 Maybe you're thinking of Bulldozer-family where FMA/math instructions of different width have a reformatting delay, like `addps` -> `addpd`.  That was only for actual math, not booleans or shuffles.  `addps` could forward to `unpcklpd` without delay, so it's not evidence of 3 separate bypass networks, or any justification for the existence of `orpd`.  It is evidence that BD kept extra stuff with vector elements to be reused, and also had special case lower latency when forwarding FMA->FMA than orps -> FMA.

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: TL:DR: Definitely was a thing on Bulldozer-family (and Jaguar/Bobcat), not K8/K10, but not for `orpd` / `orps`.  Only actual math.  Assuming Agner Fog's summary is fully accurate.  For K8/K10 did consider a reformatting delay as a hypothesis, but rejected it based on only seeing extra latency between i-vec and FP, not between single and double precision instructions on that uarch family.